# Jquery mobile select input

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile select menu, form calculator works in browser Firefox but not in android. When hitting submit button in browser it works as expected but when I do it in android the spinner loads and sends back to my home page.

```
            <form id="thermalgrowth">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="t">
                            T:
                        </label>
                        <input id="t" placeholder=""  name="t" value="" type="number" step="0.001" min="0"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="l">
                            L:
                        </label>
                        <input id="l" placeholder=""  name="l" value="" type="number" step="0.001" min="0"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>


                <div data-role="fieldcontain">  
                    <label for="c" class="select">C:</label>                    
                        <select name="c" id="c" >
                            <option value=".000006">Carbon Steel</option>
                            <option value=".0000059">Cast Iron</option>
                            <option value=".0000095">Stainless Steel</option>
                            <option value=".0000073">Nickel Steel</option>
                            <option value=".00001">Bronze</option>
                        </select>
                </div>                  

                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a"><button id="reset" type="reset" data-theme="c" name="reset">Reset</button></div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b"><button id="submit" type="submit" data-theme="b" name="submit" >Submit</button></div>
                </div>

                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="tg">
                            Thermal Growth
                        </label>
                        <input id="tg" placeholder=""  name="tg" type="number" disabled="disabled"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript"><!--

                    function calculate () {

                        var t = $('#t').val();
                        var l = $('#l').val();
                        var c = $('#c').val();                  

                        var tg = Number(t) * l * c ;

                        $('#tg').val( tg.toFixed(3) );

                        // submit event functions must return false,
                        // to tell the browser not to load a new page.
                        return false;
                    }

                    $('#thermalgrowth').submit( calculate );
                    $('#reset').click(function() {
                        $('#t').val('0').number('refresh');
                        $('#l').val('0').number('refresh');
                        $('#tg').val('0').number('refresh');
                    });

                </script>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting rid of the `<!--` thing in your script element? That may be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Catalano,

I guess either there's a parse error or a runtime error. The unclosed `<!--` may be an issue. The console should tell you.

Odd that you should use `Number()` for `t` but not for the other two values. Automatic type conversion should handle it but, at least for completeness, you could try :

```
var tg = Number(t) * Number(l) * Number(c) ;
```

You might also try wrapping the whole thing in `$(function(){...})` and putting it in the document `<head>`.

Comment: Changed var tg = Number(t) * Number(l) * Number(c) ; and did not notice the <!-- in previous build but deleted anyways, and worked like a charm.